# Mongodb $graphLookup aggregation inconsistent ouput order and sorting

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have this  aggregation operation, and it's giving me the correct output, but with an inconsistent order. When I reload, the nested output array (posteriorThread) changes the order of the documents, and there seems to be no rhyme or reason!

I'm confused why the order keeps changing, and I would like to know why it's happening, but I figured I would just sort it, which I did, but I'm having trouble grouping it back together.

I'll show you both of my broken solutions below, but essentially I want output 1 but with the correct order. I'm using mongoose, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Thanks.

## 1: Inconsistent order solution

```
const posteriorThread = await Comment.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: post.threadDescendant,
        },
      },
      {
        $graphLookup: {
          from: 'comments',
          startWith:'$threadDescendant',
          connectFromField: 'threadDescendant',
          connectToField: '_id',
          as: 'posteriorThread',
        },
      },
    ]);
```

## OUTPUT: 1

```
posteriorThread [
  {
    "_id": "000",
    "name": "foo bar",
    "text": "testing one",
    "threadDescendant": "123",
    "posteriorThread": [
      {
        "_id": "234",
        "name": "foo bar",
        "text": "testing four",
        "threadDescendant": "345"
      },
      {
        "_id": "345",
        "name": "foo bar",
        "text": "testing three",
      }, 
      {
        "_id": "123",
        "name": "foo bar",
        "text": "testing two",
        "threadDescendant": "234"
      },  
    ]
  }
]
```

## 2: Correct older but lose root document

```
    const posteriorThread = await Comment.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: post.threadDescendant,
        },
      },
      {
        $graphLookup: {
          from: 'comments',
          startWith: '$threadDescendant',
          connectFromField: 'threadDescendant',
          connectToField: '_id',
          as: 'posteriorThread',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$posteriorThread',
      },
      {
        $sort: { 'posteriorThread.depth': 1 },
      },
      {
        $group: { _id: '$_id', posteriorThread: { $push: '$posteriorThread' } },
      },
    ]);
```

## OUTPUT 2:

```
posteriorThread [
  {
    "_id": "000",
    "posteriorThread": [
      {
        "_id": "123",
        "name": "foo bar",
        "text": "testing two",
        "threadDescendant": "234"
      },  
      {
        "_id": "234",
        "name": "foo bar",
        "text": "testing four",
        "threadDescendant": "345"
      },
      {
        "_id": "345",
        "name": "foo bar",
        "text": "testing three",
      }, 
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$graphLookup` pipeline stage doesn't offer any built-in sorting capability, thus your second approach is correct. You just need to use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) in order to preserve root object's fields. You can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and special `$$ROOT` variable to avoid specifying each field explicitly:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        posteriorThread: { $push: "$posteriorThread" },
        root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "root.posteriorThread": 0
    }
},
{
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
                { posteriorThread: "$posteriorThread" },
                "$root"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mYagC2oMA4e)

Comment: I simplified it for the question, but I have many more fields. Is there anyway to persist all fields from the root doc without adding each field by hand?

Comment: @7iiBob sure, see my modified answer

Comment: I knew I needed to use root! I had tried something with root, but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed.